# What is the need of uploading CSV file for performance testing in blazemeter?

Tags: testing

I am new in Testing world and just started working on performance and load testing, I just want to know that while we record script in Blazemeter and upload a jmx file for test then why we upload a CSV file with it and What data we need to enter in that CSV file. pls help.
Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You can generate data for testing (e.g. user names and passwords etc.) and save in CSV format and then read them from CSV file and use in your test scenarios if it's needed. Please refer to the Blazemeter documentation - [Using CSV DATA SET CONFIG](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG)